# Return modified list using max of second value in each sub-list

Tags: python

I have a nested list, such as:

```
[[5117, 1556658900, u'29.3'], [5117, 1556659200, u'29.2'], [5117, 1556659500, u'29.0'], 
 [67097, 1556658900, u'28.61'], [67097, 1556659200, u'28.5'], [67097, 1556659500, u'28.44'],
 [69370, 1556658900, u'30.0'], [69370, 1556659200, u'29.90'], [69370, 1556659500, u'29.94']]
```

I would like to return a modified nested list that contains one entry for each of the unique identifiers in each element (the first integer in each). The entry to retain should correspond to the maximum of the second value.

For example, I would like to return:

```
[[5117, 1556659500, u'29.0'], [67097, 1556659500, u'28.44'],[69370, 1556659500, u'29.94']]
```

Is there an efficient way to do this with `itertools` or otherwise?

The max of the second value may not always correspond to the last entry for the identifier group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The desired result will be in `d.values()`.

```
d = {}
for r in rows:
    if r[1] > d.get(r[1], (0, 0, 0))[1]:
        d[r[0]] = r
```

Or this way:

```
# Not sure why anyone would worry about imports from the standard library.
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

maxes = [
    max(g, key = itemgetter(1))
    for k, g in groupby(sorted(rows), key = itemgetter(0))
]
```

Comment: This answer is fastest: `7.152557373046875e-06 seconds`

Comment: I couldn't agree more on the standard imports for anything running in Python, but keep in mind that some people cross-compile Python to other languages and not all libraries will be equally well-support in the target languages. It's a fringe concern, but one to keep in mind when people insist on 'no imports'.

Comment: Also, note that, although most solutions provided here yield correct results, they don't always yield the *same* results. Some solutions ignore order, others change order in a predictable way through the use of sorted. You may prefer one solution to another depending on whether you like some secondary selection (smallest id first for example) or some secondary requirement (first in original order first for example).

Comment: And finally, for anyone using a solution like this for larger data sets: this solution is actually not the fastest. Running the cProfiler on all solutions with a data set of 1 million items, this solution slows down to be about 10x slower than most of the others. It appears that the order of growth of this algorithm is far less favourable than the others, even though it may perform well on small data sets.

Comment: I am mystified by these comments about performance. Obviously, neither was written with raw speed in mind. Look elsewhere if you care about such issues.

Answer (score 3):

I would prefer a simple and straightforward solution in this case, although it's not the most efficient:

```
from random import randint

# data = [[5117, 1556658900, u'29.3'], [5117, 1556659200, u'29.2'], [5117, 1556659500, u'29.0'],
#         [67097, 1556658900, u'28.61'], [67097, 1556659200, u'28.5'], [67097, 1556659500, u'28.44'],
#         [69370, 1556658900, u'30.0'], [69370, 1556659200, u'29.90'], [69370, 1556659500, u'29.94']]


data = [[randint(0, 1000), randint(0, 10000), str(randint(0, 100))] for _ in range(1000000)]

def max_recs(recs, identifier, value):
    results = {}
    for rec in recs:
        if rec[identifier] not in results or rec[value] > results[rec[identifier]][value]:
            results[rec[identifier]] = rec
    return list(results.values())


def max_recs_fixed(recs):
    results = {}
    for rec in recs:
        if rec[0] not in results or rec[1] > results[rec[0]][1]:
            results[rec[0]] = rec
    return list(results.values())


print(max_recs(data, 0, 1))
print(max_recs_fixed(data))
```

Although this makes many temporary references to elements in the original list, which are then later overwritten by references to elements with a higher value, I feel this isn't an efficiency problem.

The main cost will be in the many repeated dictionary look-ups, which are hard to avoid given the nature of the problem. But you're taking advantage of the very efficient implementation of this in Python itself.

If you don't care about being to able to tell the function which indices to use for `identifier` and `value`, you'll find the `max_recs_fixed` is slightly faster than `max_recs`. Using a profiles for a million randomly generated records, it was about 5% faster on average.

As the OP appears to prefer simplicity, this would be minimal:

```
data = [[5117, 1556658900, u'29.3'], [5117, 1556659200, u'29.2'], [5117, 1556659500, u'29.0'],
        [67097, 1556658900, u'28.61'], [67097, 1556659200, u'28.5'], [67097, 1556659500, u'28.44'],
        [69370, 1556658900, u'30.0'], [69370, 1556659200, u'29.90'], [69370, 1556659500, u'29.94']]


results = {}
for rec in data:
    if rec[0] not in results or rec[1] > results[rec[0]][1]:
        results[rec[0]] = rec
print(list(results.values()))
```

Since there is a number of very different results and some claims were made about the speed, here's some code that has all of them in a fair comparison, you can use cProfile or similar tools to compare performance:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
from random import randint
from collections import defaultdict

# generate a random set of 1000000 items matching the example format
data = [[randint(0, 1000), randint(0, 10000), str(randint(0, 100))] for _ in range(1000000)]


def max_recs(recs):
    results = {}
    for rec in recs:
        if rec[0] not in results or rec[1] > results[rec[0]][1]:
            results[rec[0]] = rec
    return list(results.values())


def convert(lst):
    biggest = defaultdict(int)
    for ident, value, _ in lst:
        if value > biggest[ident]:
            biggest[ident] = value
    return list(filter(lambda l: l[1] == biggest[l[0]], lst))


def process_list(l):
    d = {}
    for item in l:
        key = item[0]
        if key in d:
            if item[1] > d[key][1]:
                d[key] = item
        else:
            d[key] = item
    return list(d.values())


def naive(l):
    temp = []
    temp2 = []
    li = sorted(l, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
    for i in li:
        if i[0] not in temp:
            temp2.append(i)
            temp.append(i[0])

    return temp2


def another(recs):
    return [
        max(g, key=itemgetter(1))
        for k, g in groupby(sorted(recs), key=itemgetter(0))
    ]


max_recs_res = max_recs(data)
convert_res = convert(data)
process_list_res = process_list(data)
naive_res = naive(data)
another_res = another(data)


def cs(result):
    # return a set of id, value combinations of a result, for comparison
    return {(i, v) for i, v, _ in result}


# check that all results have the same id, value combinations (they do)
assert cs(max_recs_res) == cs(convert_res) == cs(process_list_res) == cs(naive_res) == cs(another_res)
# check that all results have the same number of solutions (convert_res includes *duplicate* id, val combinations!)
assert len(max_recs_res) == len(process_list_res) == len(naive_res) == len(another_res)  # == len(convert_res)
```

Running cProfile, I got these results running them.

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Records   | max_recs | convert | process_list | naive  | another | notes          |
| 1000x100  | 14ms     | 49ms    | 13ms         | 110ms  | 83ms    |                |
| 1x10000   | 2ms      | 4ms     | 2ms          | 80ms   | 9ms     | 3x rounded avg |
| 1x1000000 | 216ms    | 400ms   | 258ms        | 7234ms | 2416ms  | 3x rounded avg |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Running fewer than 1000 records simply doesn't yield meaningful values - results vary wildly if you time them individually, so a 1000 100 record run times were combined. But on the whole they are equally fast, executing almost immediately.

For larger data sets, the results are pretty clear and most of the algorithms scale linearly with the data set size, except for `naive` and `another` which scale exponentially. (if someone wants to analyse and provide exact order, be my guest)

Comment: I just noticed that my `fixed` solution is virtually identical to @Alassane Ndiaye's - except for the `list()` wrapper and the single line condition, and avoiding shadowing the `dict` type.

Comment: And for laughs, I ran the same code against the other solutions, which was (predictably) identical for @Alassane's solution, and about twice as fast as @Christian's `convert()`

Comment: Yeah @Grismar, lol, I knew my answer wasn't as efficient as it could've been. All those dictionary lookups start to add up. Plus I should really be using a list comp rather than `filter` + `lambda`.

Comment: This answer is very well explained and would help someone in future (op should consider accepting this).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that iterates once over the entire list. You can use a dictionary to keep track of the highest entry for each identifier.

```
def process_list(l):
    dict = {}
    for item in l:
        key = item[0]
        if key in dict:
            if item[1] > dict[key][1]:
                dict[key] = item
        else:
            dict[key] = item
    return dict.values()

l = [[5117, 1556658900, u'29.3'], [5117, 1556659200, u'29.2'], [5117, 1556659500, u'29.0'],
 [67097, 1556658900, u'28.61'], [67097, 1556659200, u'28.5'], [67097, 1556659500, u'28.44'],
 [69370, 1556658900, u'30.0'], [69370, 1556659200, u'29.90'], [69370, 1556659500, u'29.94']]
print(process_list(l))
```

Answer (score 1):

My approach would be to make a mapping of each identifier with its biggest value, and then filter your list using that mapping:

```
from collections import defaultdict


def convert(lst):
    biggest = defaultdict(int)
    for ident, value, _ in lst:
        if value > biggest[ident]:
            biggest[ident] = value
    return [l for l in lst if l[1] == biggest[l[0]]]


lst = [[5117, 1556658900, u'29.3'], [5117, 1556659200, u'29.2'], [5117, 1556659500, u'29.0'], 
 [67097, 1556658900, u'28.61'], [67097, 1556659200, u'28.5'], [67097, 1556659500, u'28.44'],
 [69370, 1556658900, u'30.0'], [69370, 1556659200, u'29.90'], [69370, 1556659500, u'29.94']]
print(convert(lst)) 
# output: [[5117, 1556659500, '29.0'], [67097, 1556659500, '28.44'], [69370, 1556659500, '29.94']]
```

After some reflection, I rewrote my above code:

```
lst = [[5117, 1556658900, u'29.3'], [5117, 1556659200, u'29.2'], [5117, 1556659500, u'29.0'], 
[67097, 1556658900, u'28.61'], [67097, 1556659200, u'28.5'], [67097, 1556659500, u'28.44'],
[69370, 1556658900, u'30.0'], [69370, 1556659200, u'29.90'], [69370, 1556659500, u'29.94']]

new_list = [max(g, key=lambda l: l[1]) for _, g in groupby(lst, key=lambda l: l[0])]
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be naive:

```
li = [[5117, 1556658900, u'29.3'], [5117, 1556659200, u'29.2'], [5117, 1556659500, u'29.0'],
 [67097, 1556658900, u'28.61'], [67097, 1556659200, u'28.5'], [67097, 1556659500, u'28.44'],
 [69370, 1556658900, u'30.0'], [69370, 1556659200, u'29.90'], [69370, 1556659500, u'29.94']]

temp = []
temp2 = []
li = sorted(li, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
for i in li:
    if i[0] not in temp:
        temp2.append(i)
        temp.append(i[0])

print(temp2)
```

But you can modify it to make it efficient.

> Edit:
>
> I would say, this is not the best answer, so op should select others
>   (so, that in future someone else will get helped).

Comment: I prefer this for it's simplicity and no need for additional imports. All these answers seem like they will do the job equally well, however.

Comment: Note that the solutions provided by @Alassane and myself below don't require any imports either (my imports simply allowed for generation of a larger test set) and that they perform way faster and require less memory.

Comment: @Ruturaj, it's not incorrect, but inefficient in both terms of time and space required. The OP asked for "an efficient way to do this". It was also posted after other more efficient answers were already posted, so I figured it made sense to vote it down, since it's not exactly useful to people with the same question - in spite of it being accepted as the answer in this case.

Comment: @grismar I think I posted my answer about the same time as others. Also, I noted in my question that it is a naive approach, but serves the purpose. I think the answer should not get accepted (I couldn't agree with you more in that case), that said, it should not be down-voted either.

Comment: Thanks for making you case clear, I appreciate you being civil about it. I re-read the instructions on down-voting and Stackoverflow says "downvote whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect"

I agree with you that this does not apply, although I still feel your answer sidesteps the requirement of efficiency, and could be considered incorrect in that light. I'll remove the down-vote, because I have to agree with you that it doesn't meet the bar set by the site. But perhaps you can up-vote the best one?

Comment: @ruturaj - you'll need to make an edit to the answer for me to be able to remove the down-vote, as it's currently locked in and I have no way of changing it.

Comment: @Grismar thanks, I edited my answer. I agree. I upvoted your's (being well explained - 0.00025463104248046875 seconds) and FMc's (fastest - 7.152557373046875e-06 seconds).

Comment: I'm running into a bit of a technicality here, SO still doesn't allow me to remote the down-vote. I'll try again in a bit. Also, just as an aside: when running timing tests with something as relatively simple as this code, it's generally better to time a large number of executions instead of a single once, since there are many outside factors that could affect a single exection (I'm not saying your number couldn't be right, I didn't check, just that the method is shifty).

Comment: I agree. Thanks @Grismar.